# Python, SQLAlchemy: Storing business hours as binary bitmask

Tags: python, sql, algorithm, binary, sqlalchemy

I am programming in Python and using SQLAlchemy to store business hours.
The business hours are composed of three parts:

1. The days of the week stored in binary as a bitmask
2. the time the business opens,
3. the time the business closes.

The bitmask works like this. There are 7 digits, which are either 0 or 1, which will represent different sequences of weekdays. Each position represents a day of the week. The first position stands for Monday and the last for Sunday. For example, 1111100 represents Monday-Friday, and 0000111, Friday-Saturday. Also, I am storing the hours in military time, 0600 meaning 6AM and 1800 meaning 6PM.

```python
hours = Table('hours', Base.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("businessid", Integer, ForeignKey('businesses.id')),
    Column("days", Integer),
    Column("open", Integer),
    Column("close", Integer),
)

class Hours(object):
    def __init__(self, days=None, open=None, close=None):
        self.days = days
        self.open = open
        self.close = close

mapper(Hours, hours)
mapper(Business, businesses, properties={
    'hours': relationship(Hours, backref='business'),
})
```

What is the Pythonic way to figure out when two of the bitmasks representing the days of the week overlap? And also, what is the best way to find out if a business is currently open when given two pairs of Hours objects?

Comment: So, this assumes that on the days that are set, the hours are the same for those days?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by overlap?

Comment: By overlap I mean, conflict. Say I have business hours stored for a particular business, M-F 8AM to 5PM. Then I have someone attempt to add another Hours object for F-Su 9AM to 4PM. These times conflict, and therefore must be reconciled.

Comment: I see. You want your basic bit-manipulation techniques. For example, M-F would be `1111100` and F-Su would be `0000111`. The "AND" of these two would be `0000100`, so you want the "AND" result to be zero for a non-overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as checking days of the week, if by binary you mean a string of the form '1011011':

```
overlap = [n for n in range(7) if (bitmask1[n] == bitmask2[n] == '1')]
```

will give you a list of the numbers (from 0-6) of the overlapping days -- [4] for Friday overlapping.

```
overlap = ''.join(('1' if (bitmask1[n] == bitmask2[n] == '1') else '0') for n in range(7))
```

Will give you a new bitmask string -- '00000100' for Friday overlapping.

If you're actually storing the number as an integer, it's probably easiest to just convert it to one, either with `bin(bitmask)[2:]` or `"{0:b}".format(bitmask)`.

I'm not sure what you mean by "currently open ... two pairs of hours objects". Do you want the overlap of the two pairs of hours? If they are whole hours, its easy:

```
[hour for hour in range(firsthour, secondhour) if hour in range(openinghour, closinghour)
```

Will give you a list of the hours in both ranges.

Comment: @awfullyjohn Please remember to accept answers to your question if the answers have helped you.